# Exception to L'Hopital

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Rearding L'Hopital's rule for the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case:
Assume $a<c<b$ and $f,g$ are differentiable functions on $(a,b)$\{$c$} such that $g'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$.  If $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\infty$ and there is an $L$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L$$ implies $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$$
Assuming $L=\infty$, does this remain valid?  Are there any counterexamples?  I can't think of any so am going to start working on a proof that it remains valid in this case but wondering if I'm missing an obvious exception.

Comment: You mean $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c} \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$?

Comment: yes.  fixed.  thank you.

Comment: If $L=\infty,$ then I must change this way. I think that we can have some other types: $\dfrac{0}{0}, 1^{\infty}, 0^0,\infty^0,\infty-\infty.$ You can reference in [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055368/counterexample-to-lhopitals-rule-as-an-exercise-in-understanding-analysis?rq=1).

Comment: Usually, when one writes things like $\lim_{x\to c} h(x) = L$ it is understood that the limit actually exists and is $L$. Of course, write things like $\lim_{x\to c} h(x) = \infty$ means that $h$ doesn't have a limit and that $h(x)$ is arbitrarily large.

Comment: My reading is that this remains valid. That is, it is within the range of the usual statement of Lhopital's rule. Always has been. Johann Bernoulli discovered it a long time ago, and it has endured. Thus, there will be no counter-example. For a proof, you can see the Wikipedia page, for instance.

Comment: Both $L=\infty$ and $L=-\infty$ work fine.